I HAVE A METAMASK WALLET UNABLE TO WITHDRAW TOKENS HOLDING FROM IT. PLEASE HELP
Someone scammed me for 1000$ saying that he will give me a wallet having 2000$ inside to withdraw. i sent him 1000$ but in return i only have a metamask wallet havin 2000$ inside but i am unable to withdraw. its a kind of scamming wallet. please help me recover my money if possible.
